# Is it possible to do a complete, clean, uninstall of Phantom JS after it has been compiled in place?

Tags: linux, uninstall, build

I’ve just built and compiled [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org) for use on a Raspberry Pi.

To do this, I cloned the [GitHub repository](http://github.com/ariya/phantomjs), than used a `build.sh` command that—after 5 hours—has generated few executables, copied or moved other few files, and so on.

I think build is not 100% successful, so I’d like to restart.

I there a way to undo a PhantomJS build?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems that PhantomJS—by default—doesn’t install it’s files anywhere outside of it’s build directory. According to [the official PhantomJS documentation](http://phantomjs.org/build.html) on building the software:

> This produces a statically built `bin/phantomjs`. This is a
>   self-contained executable, it can be moved to a different directory or
>   another machine.

Which means that if you did a `git clone` of the source software to a directory named `phantomjs/` and then ran `./build.sh` in that directory, you can just remove the `bin/` directory in `phantomjs/`. Or just get rid of the whole `phantomjs/` directory and pull a new `git clone` to attempt to build it again.

But honestly, when I recently faced the task of installing PhantomJS on Ubuntu 12.04, I winced at the idea of dealing with source code build taking hours to compile. So I installed PhantomJS via NPM (Node Package Manager)—which is a part of NodeJS instead. This gives you a nice, clean, already “built” version of PhantomJS in minutes instead of waiting hours for the build/compile to manually finish.

This is how I did it in Ubuntu 12.04:

#### First, install Node.js and NPM (Node Package Manager)

Install `python-software-properties` like this:

```
sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
```

Next add the NodeSource PPA repository to the system like this:

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup | sudo bash -
```

With that done, run `aptitude` update like this:

```
sudo aptitude update
```

And now, install Node.js and NPM like this:

```
sudo aptitude install nodejs
```

Now NodeJS and NPM will be installed. You can check the versions by running the following commands:

```
nodejs --version
npm --version
```

The returned versions should be `v0.10.33` for NodeJS and `1.4.28` for NPM.

#### Next, install PhantomJS via NPM (Node Package Manager)

Now install PhantomJS via NPM like this:

```
sudo npm install -g phantomjs
```

Or use this variant of the command which uses `phantomjs-prebuilt` if you find `phantomjs` to be depreciated when you run the NPM command:

```
sudo npm install -g phantomjs-prebuilt
```

After it installs check the version by running this command:

```
phantomjs --version
```

The version number should be something like `1.9.8`.

If that somehow fails, then set the NPM registry like this:

```
npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/
```

And if there are SSL issues connecting to the NPM repository, disable the strict SSL settings:

```
npm config set strict-ssl false
```

Once that’s all done, you will have PhantomJS installed successfully via NPM.

**UPDATE:** The original poster indicates that they are compiling PhantomJS for use on a Raspberry Pi. If that is the case, one can install NodeJS and NPM on a Raspberry Pi via the methods [explained here](http://weworkweplay.com/play/raspberry-pi-nodejs/) as well [as here](http://joshondesign.com/2013/10/23/noderpi).

Comment: Super answer, thanks. But my Linux is, for precision because I omitted this info, a raspberry pi. So there is no legacy binary package on node package repository usefull for my little friend.

Comment: But I cannot install phantomJs using npm. Has some strange errors about using phantomJs as a dependency of phantomJs itselfs

Comment: Small update, `phantomjs` is now deprecated with npm so you should rather install `npm install -g phantomjs-prebuilt`